# How to do a Sunburnt Query on exact term

Tags: python, solr, sunburnt

Trying to search for exactly "11000060K2"

```
    from solr import SolrConnection
    from sunburnt import RawString

    term = "11000060K2"
    solr_conn = SolrConnection()
    scoreDocs = solr_conn.si.query(activityemail=RawString(term)).paginate(start=0, rows=1000).execute()
    params_dict = scoreDocs.params
    for key, keyvalue in params_dict:
        logging.debug ("param %s    value %s "  %(key, keyvalue) )
```

Returns:

```
param start    value 0 
param q    value activityemail:11000060K2 
param rows    value 1000
```

And a bunch of results that match other terms.

I want it to return only documents that match 11000060K2 with a query that returns / looks like:

```
param q    value activityemail:"11000060K2"
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How you can achieve this is going to depend on your Solr schema configuration (`schema.xml`), and in particular, the field type associated with your `activityemail` field. At present, if you're receiving multiple results back, it may be because of a filter/analyzer on the given field type causing multiple matches. Solr's `solr.StrField` field class sounds like it would be the best choice for your field, as the values of fields of this type will be stored verbatim and queries will be exact matches.

If you're already using the field elsewhere for other purposes, you might consider creating a new field just for this purpose.

So, including this in your `schema.xml` will introduce a field type named `string`:

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
```

If you've followed examples included with Solr's default install, then you may already have such a field type available.  Your field definition should look something like:

```
<field name="activityemail" type="string" ... />
```

where the ellipsis represents your various other options associated with the field.

After restarting Solr and re-indexing your documents, this field can be queried using just the string you mentioned:

```
from solr import SolrConnection
term = "11000060K2"
solr_conn = SolrConnection()
scoreDocs = solr_conn.si.query(activityemail=term).execute()
print scoreDocs.result.docs
```